# Github Action deploy a docker container to a server

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions, continuous-delivery

I believe this question is useful for anyone **uses GitHub action** and **has an ssh server** and **want to use docker** to run their application.

For Github action, it is easy to set up a container to run in that *github-host runner* but no documentation of deploying this container to **non-orchestration system**.

If I have a cloud server with ssh access and **dont want to use any orchestration system**.

How to achieve the following two workflows?

---

First

How to set up the GitHub action to

1. ssh into that cloud server and
2. install docker in that server if not installed
3. in that cloud server, run the container from the image defined in the GitHub repo Dockerfile (so the build happen in the cloud server)

---

Second

How to set up the GitHub action to

1. Build the image from the Dockerfile in the **github-host runner**
2. ssh into that cloud server and
3. install docker in that server if not installed
4. in that cloud server, run the container from the build generated in **step1** (so the build actually happen in the GitHub-host runner)

---

Actually, which one is better?